# Can I transfer biometrics information for a UK visitor visa to a Canadian visitor visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, canada

I gave biometrics for my UK visitor visa application 3 weeks ago. I now want to apply for a Canadian visitor visa and the biometrics center is literally the same one I just travelled to and gave my previous biometrics. Is it possible to use the same biometric confirmation? I know this may be a long shot but it would really save me a lot of time and effort.

Comment: No. That rather defeats the purpose of biometrics.

Comment: Probably not, but if it is the same service center handling the applications give them a call and ask to be sure, worst case they say no and confirm you have to visit them again.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that would be a great way for someone to create fraudulent entries.

The center might be the same, but your data is going to two completely different systems so you'll have to visit again and provide the fingerprint data.